# SEO Impact of moving the subfolder of a website to the root folder

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

I have a website `example.com/blog/a-random-post`. It's already indexed on Google Search and Bing Search.

I'm working to change the host provider to Google Cloud but am worried about the impact it could have on search engines to find it because the new URL would be `example.com/a-random-post`.

PS: I couldn't add the subfolder on Google Cloud, so that's the reason I'm willing to remove the `/blog` subfolder.

Can someone help?

Comment: Just use a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) from the old URL to the new URL and you should be fine. There _may_ be a little dip, but you should recover over time if everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

A 301 Permanent Redirect from the old to new URL should work totally fine. Even if you see a ranking drop it should be on the top after few days (When I made changes like these, I observed the results within 15 days).

If you do not want to take the risk and have time to understand how this could affect your website, you can take a page from your blog and move it to the root folder following a 301 Permanent Redirect. Based on the results you can observe in the next 15 days, you can make your decision accordingly.

> `Old URL: example.com/blog/page to new URL example.com/page`

If you're doing this, make sure you index your new page as well.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: I couldn't add the subfolder on Google Cloud, so that's the reason I'm willing to remove the `/blog` subfolder.

Based on your question, it sounds as though you're attempting to use Google's Cloud Storage for your website.

If that's true, WordPress won't work there -- I highly recommend maintaining your site's structure and learning how to better use GCP before moving forward. WordPress would require either a VM or an App Engine instance in order to work, due to the PHP back end. [Google has some recommended implementations.](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/)

If I'm mistaken, I still highly recommend maintaining your site's structure and avoiding redirects -- unless your site is used *only* as a WordPress blog, in which case feel free to 301 redirect everything.